# How to render a varying numbers of tables based on user input in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

In an R shiny app I'm attempting to render a varying number of tables based on user input. As an example, I've created the following app:

```
# ui.R

fluidPage(
  numericInput("numeric.input", "Select Number of Tables:", 0, min = 0),
  tableOutput("table")
)

# server.R

data(iris)

function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderTable({
    head(iris)
  })
}
```

What I'd like for this app to do is to generate a number of tables dependent on the value selected for `numeric.input`. Currently `numeric.input` doesn't influence the app and is only shown for example. If `numeric.input` is set to zero, I'd like for the app to display no copies of the table, if `numeric.input` is set to one, I'd like for the app to display one copy of the table, etc.

Is something like this possible in R Shiny?

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue by using the [R Shiny Gallery app on creating UI in a loop](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html), but [rendering the UI loop within the R Shiny server](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html). The following code works correctly:

```
# ui.R

fluidPage(
  numericInput("numeric.input", "Select Number of Tables:", 1, min = 1),
  uiOutput("tables")
)

# server.R

data(iris)

function(input, output) {

  # Rendering tables dependent on user input.
  observeEvent(input$numeric.input, {
    lapply(1:input$numeric.input, function(i) {
      output[[paste0('table', i)]] <- renderTable({
        head(iris)
      })
    })
  })

  # Rendering UI and outputtign tables dependent on user input.
  output$tables <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:input$numeric.input, function(i) {
      uiOutput(paste0('table', i))
    })
  })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is simple and straightforward. Just putting out the usage of the `insertUI` and `removeUI` for this purpose based on the link provided in comments by @r2evans.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("numericinput", "Select Number of Tables:", 0, min = 0),
  tags$div(id = 'tabledisplay')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  inserted <- c()
  observeEvent(input$numericinput, {
    tablenum <- input$numericinput
    id <- paste0('table', tablenum)
    if (input$numericinput > length(inserted)) {
      insertUI(selector = '#tabledisplay',
               ui = tags$div(h4(
                 paste0("Table number ", input$numericinput)
               ), tags$p(renderTable({
                 head(iris)
               })),
               id = id))
      inserted <<- c(id, inserted)
    }
    else {
      inserted <- sort(inserted)
      removeUI(selector = paste0('#', inserted[length(inserted)]))          
      inserted <<- inserted[-length(inserted)]
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```